# How to read more than Text file in springbatch item reader

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin, spring-batch-job-monitoring, spring-batch-excel

I have to read a text file from item reader into my item processor. But now I have to read more than one file in my item processor.

And I have one more doubt in text file reader: how to read a text file without using file concept?

Comment: Use the decorator pattern to nest/wrap `ItemReader`s.  The object passed to the processor contains the attributes from reading both files.  Try it out, and if problems post the code.  What do you mean _read a text file without using file concept_?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...

Comment: I need to Read a text file in java but I don't want to use any file reader and buffered reader concept  is any other way to read a file

Comment: Why don't you want to use SpringBatch Reader? any specific need?